# The convenience Win+R/Run command

Tags: windows, shortcut-keys

How can I achieve the convenience the <kbd>Win+r</kbd>, more widely known as [*Run command*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_command), provides in Windows, in Ubuntu?

**E.g.:**

1. Go to path
2. Open a file in default application

Comment: Please explain what Win+R does for the uninitiated. The **e.g.** you give I would say is trivial: hit the Enter key.

Comment: @zwets [run command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_command)

Comment: I'm not sure, isn't terminal more than enough for that purpose?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The actual key combination can usually be configured, but on many Linux Desktop Environments, including Ubuntu Unity, <kbd>ALT + F2</kbd> opens the "run" command.

Answer (score 4):

You can run achieve most of the things by using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> command.  You can run commands directly without opening the terminal. You can open files and folders using this command by specifying the path.

Answer (score 3):

Default <kbd>Alt - F2</kbd> hotkey, at least for me, is very different from <kbd>Win - R</kbd> hotkey -- which would search the list of commands based on what you type.

You can achieve the same result with **GRun** tool.  It maintains the history and starts searching it the moment you start typing.

To install: `sudo apt-get install grun`

To launch: `grun`

To make it a drop-in replacement, you can configure a hotkey <kbd>Win - R</kbd> to launch `grun`.